# ¿Cómo cambiar el key pair de una instancia EC2?

Tags: aws, ec2

Hola quisiera saber como puedo hacer para cambiar o reemplazar el key de una instancia EC2 que está corriendo.

Comment: Tienes acceso a la instancia actualmente via ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via AWS no es posible. Las claves se copian en el momento en el que la instancia se crea y no es posible modificarlas posteriormente.

Sin embargo, de acuerdo a lo comentado en [este enlace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair) puedes seguir una serie de pasos para modificar la key pair:

- Para la instancia de EC2
- Busca el volumen de la instancia (de ahora en adelante volA) y le haces *detach*
- Crea una nueva instancia usando el nuevo key pair (para reducir costes puede ser una T1.micro)
- Adjunta volA a esta nueva instancia como /dev/svdf o (/dev/sdf)
- Conéctate via SSH a la nueva instancia
- Monta volA:

  ```
  $ sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/tmp
  ```
- Copia el contenido de `authorized_keys` a volA:

  ```
  $ copy ~/.ssh/autorized_keys /mnt/tmp/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- Vuelve a adjuntar volA a tu instancia
- Termina la instancia T1.micro
- Inicia tu instancia y trata de hacer login usando el nuevo key pair